# one encrypted VG on multiple physical devices

Tags: debian, lvm, cryptsetup

I have a problem with my Linux setup under Debian Bullseye. To avoid getting shot in the leg with an unstable distribution, I want to use `lvcreate` to create COW-snapshots, which I can roll back if necessary.

I run a one TB NVME and a two TB hard disk. All media is fully encrypted. The NVME has an unencrypted boot partition. The root partition is part of the volume group. The output of `sudo pvs` is

```
PV                          VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
/dev/dm-3                   vg-name lvm2 a--   <1.82t 1.77t
/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p2_crypt vg-name lvm2 a--  931.15g    0
```

The two TB hard disk is divided that only as much space is occupied as I need. About one TB are not allocated.
The NVME and the two TB hard disk are together in one volume group.
My `/etc/crypttab` looks like

```
data_crypt UUID=2xxxx /etc/keyfile luks,initramfs
nvme0n1p2_crypt UUID=0xxx none luks,initramfs,discard
```

The output of `sudo lvs` is

```
LV     VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
home   vg-name -wi-ao---- 896.15g                                                    
lvsnap vg-name swi-aos---  25.00g      root   75.17                                  
lvswap vg-name -wi-a-----  25.00g                                                    
root   vg-name owi-aos---  25.00g                                                    
swap  vg-name -wi-ao----  10.00g
```

After entering the password to decrypt **nvme0n1p2_crypt**, I get the output that a UUID can not be found. After a timeout I end up in a Busybox. Here I execute the following commands

```
cryptsetup open /dev/sda data_crypt 
Password: ***
```

This section is very long, so I usually put it in the background with `CTRG+Z` and `bg`. Nevertheless the decryption is successful.
Afterwards I run `vgchange -ay` to see all LV of the VG.
`cryptsetup status data_crypt` shows me that the crypto LV was successfully decrypted.

Finally I leave the Busybox with `exit`.
The booting of the system continues and I can log in.

I had already changed the order of the devices in the `/etc/cryptsetup`. The result was that nothing changed. I was asked for the password of *nvme0n1p2_crypt* first and complained about the missing LV before the query for *data_crypt* came.

I also tried to change my crypttab to

```
data_crypt UUID=2xxxx none luks,initramfs
nvme0n1p2_crypt UUID=0xxx none luks,initramfs,discard
```

and was running `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` after it.

The result was, that I saw twice the password question. After the first I got a warning and that the last time it was writing to `/dev/mapper/data`.
Then I inserted the password for `data_crypt`. It was very slow. After around five minutes the kernel printed `adding target dm-6 caused an alignment inconsistency: physical_block_size = … logical block size… […]`
and it stucked there, so a clean login via `tty` was not able.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the UUID in `/etc/crypttab` for `data_crypt` is correct? Try using it with the `cryptsetup` command in BusyBox, as in `cryptsetup open /dev/disk/by-uuid/2xxxx data_crypt`

Comment: Hello. Yes they are correct.